# Jenkins pipeline docker run -it

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I try this, but it doesn't work and I see **the input device is not a TTY** error.

[image: My code]

How to solve it?

Comment: you need to configure docker agent in your pipeline to reach that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

How the documentation said to use Docker in your pipeline is necessary to set up Docker agent.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the doc https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/